# can i optimize existing HTML,CSS and JS files using jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, jquery-mobile

I have existing HTML 5,CS and JS files and which are used in a web application and i want to use construct the same pages using the j query mobile (For android mobiles)? 
Can i fit my existing html 5 pages in android mobile using j query mobile?

Comment: Absolutely you can but as to what version of JQM you should use will be the deciding point because you mentioned that you have custom JS code. So check what version your JS is running Under because it may not work with the latest version of JQM. You going to need to run some tests and adjust your JS code accordingly. As for your HTML you will need to Learn how the Pages work in JQM but there shouldn't be any problems implementing what you have now to work with JQM. You can style JQM as much as you want to keep the same Style you have from the existing HTML you have.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile maintains a layout for a page. Like Page> Header>Content> Footer.
If your existing html has a such kind of construction then you can easily use your page in mobile. But dont forget to mention the data-role tage.
example
data-role="page" or data-role="content". also dont forgot to put viewport in your page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```